# prevent babel from translating import to required?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Is it possible to prevent `babel` from translating `import` to `required`?

I'm currently learning `Reactjs` and I'm using `babel` to translate `JSX` and `ES6` to `ES5` code.

However, `babel` translates `import` to `required`, which was useable using `nodejs` or `requirejs`, which I both don't want to use in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can configure Babel to leave import and export statements unchanged by using the ***@babel/preset-env*** preset with the modules: false option. This will tell Babel not to change the import and export statements.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "modules": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Great! can I also use that if I use the babel cdn?

Comment: Yes, you can use the @babel/preset-env preset with the modules: false option even if you are using the Babel CDN. 

<script src="https://cdn.babeljs.io/babel.min.js" data-presets="@babel/preset-env" data-module-options='{"modules": false}'>